# Difference between git checkout [commit] and git checkout [commit] file

Tags: git

Here both are listed as changing the Working Directory(WD).

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

However one is WD safe(git co commit) and another one unsafe.

Can you explain by giving an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git checkout  will take your repo to state where  is head . Its is considered safe as you will not lose any work . You can come back to normal state by doing git checkout master or  .

But git checkout file , will erase all the changes you made on the file and take the file to last commit state . So you lose all you work and it is not recoverable . So it is considered unsafe .

You could use git stash command to keep all the changes , which will take your code HEAD state and it is recoverable .